# Solve: $\sin x - y\cos x = z$ for $x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am working on programming a series of algorithms into a project, however I have run into trouble trying to solve this equation for $x$:

$$
\sin x - y\cos x = z
$$

It should be noted that $y$ and $z$ will be known at runtime and that $0 < x < \pi/2$.
I remember doing something like this in calculus, but it has been a while and searching the web has failed to enlighten me.

Comment: maybe this will help you http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29+-+y*cos%28x%29+%3D+z+solve+for+x

Comment: Consider setting $w(x) = sin(x)$, then $w'(x) = cos(x)$ and your equation can be rearranged to give: $[w(x)- z]/y = w'(x)$. Which is a simple ODE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *is* possible, but it is certainly not trivial. What we need to do to solve it is turn the left hand $\sin(x)-y\cos(x)$ into something of the form $c\sin(x+b)$ for some constants $c$ and $b$ which can be computed from $y$. This is because there is no way we can invert two "special functions" like $\sin$ and $\cos$ at the same time and thus need to find a different identity.

However, it turns out that this is fairly easy to do; using the identity
$$\sin(x+b)=\sin(x)\cos(b)+\cos(x)\sin(b)$$
which, gives, when multiplied by $c$
$$c\sin(x+b)=c\sin(x)\cos(b)+c\cos(x)\sin(b)$$
and we want the above to equal $\sin(x)-y\cos(x)$ - thus, if we get the coefficients of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ right, we are really requiring a simultaneous solution to:
$$c\cos(b) = 1$$
$$c\sin(b) = -y$$
What can be seen by squaring and adding the above two equations is
$$c^2(\cos(b)^2+\sin(b)^2)=c^2=1^2+(-y)^2$$
which yields $c=\sqrt{1+y^2}$. Taking the ratio of the two equations gives
$$\tan(b)=-y$$
so $b=\tan^{-1}(-y)$.

This tells us that we can write
$$\sin(x)-y\cos(x)=\sqrt{1+y^2}\sin(x-\tan^{-1}(y))$$
and to solve for the above equalling $z$ we simply undo the operations in order to receive:
$$x=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\right)+\tan^{-1}(y).$$

Comment: Nice solution. +1

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved my problem

Comment: This does not guarantee $x$ is in the required interval $(0,\pi/2)$. You could have a very large $z$, and a $y$ that is similar in size, and this final formula gives $x$ in the second quadrant. A little more attention needs to go into applying the inverse trig functions. Either that, or if there are more restrictions on $y$ and $z$, these considerations can be ignored.

Comment: @alex I suppose that's a good point, but it's easy enough to account for here. Using that $\tan^{-1}$ is in the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ will yield the correct value for the purpose here - which really is the *directed* angle to $(y,1)$. Then one only need to be concerned that $\sin^{-1}$ has a few reasonable values, but using the $\sin(x)=\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin(\pi-x)$ can yield all of them and it would largely be a simple task to figure out which is desired. (And we definitely only care about $sin^{-1}$ in $(-\pi/2,\pi)$ - otherwise, adding $\tan^{-1}(y)$ can't take it to the desired interval)

Comment: @alex.jordan Thanks for the warning, z and y will be constrained at runtime and I'll be sure to check the returned value of x.

Comment: In case this one doesn't check, the only other possible solution is $x=\pi-\arcsin\left(z/\sqrt{1+y^2}\right)+\arctan(y)$. In some conditions, _both_ will be valid solutions. For example, if $y=-1$ and $z$ is just slightly greater than $1$.

Answer (score 2):

If
$$
\sin x-y\cos x=z
$$
then
$$
x = \arcsin {z\over\sqrt{1+y^2}}+\arccos {1\over\sqrt{1+y^2}}
$$

To see why, rewrite the top equation as
$$
r(\sin x \cos q - \cos x\sin q) = z.
$$
where $y=r\sin q$ and $r\cos q = 1$. Then $r^2=1+y^2$ and $\cos q=1/r$.
This is equivalent to
$$
\sin(x-q)=z/r
$$

Also notice that $\sqrt{1+y^2}\leq z$ or there is no solution, in other words $y^2\leq z^2-1$.

Numerical check:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    incx := 0.01
    incy := 0.1
    for x := 0.0; x < math.Pi/2.0; x+=incx {
        for y := 0.0; y < 10.0; y+=incy {
            z := math.Sin(x) - y*math.Cos(x)
            r := math.Sqrt(1 + math.Pow(y, 2))
            q := math.Acos(1/r)
            x2 := math.Asin(z/r) + q
            if x - x2 > 0.0001 {
                fmt.Println(x, x2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not following the logic in your last step. Also your solution fails a quick test with x=pi/8; y=0.1; z=sin(pi/8)-.1*cos(pi/8)=0.290295

Comment: @weirdev The expression for sine and cosine in the expansion of sin(a+b) was incorrect. I've fixed it and added a numerical check.

Comment: すみません, I believe the formula you meant to use was $$\cos(x - q) = \cos(x)\cos(q) - \sin(x)\sin(q)$$ so the final answer should be : $$\arccos\left(\frac{-z}{\sqrt{1 + y^2}}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + y^2}}\right)$$

Comment: $$\sin(x - q) = z/r$$ should be $$-\cos(x - q) = z/r$$

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you add two sinusoids of the same frequency, you get back another sinusoid of that frequency.  Their phases and amplitudes don't have to be the same.

So first write:

$$\sin(x) - y\cos(x) = z$$

as a more standard amplitude/phase form:

$$\sin(x) - y\sin(\pi/2 - x) = \sin(x) + y\sin(x - \pi/2)$$

$$1~\sin(x + 0) + y~\sin(x - \pi/2) = z$$

And now we have the sum of two sinusoids with amplitude/phase being $1, 0$ and $y, -\pi/2$ (and both have frequency $\frac{1}{2\pi}$).

To add them using polar form , $\angle$, use the formula

> $$f(x) = A_1\sin(fx + p_1) + A_2\sin(fx + p_2)$$
>   can be simplified as
>   $$f(x) = A_3\sin(fx + p_3)$$
>   given that 
>   $$A_1 ~\angle~p_1 + A_2 ~\angle~p_2 = A_3 ~\angle~p_3$$

So we have 
$$A_3 \sin(x + p_3) = z$$

for 
$$A_3~\angle~ p_3 = 1~\angle~0 + y~\angle~-\pi/2$$

This is a basic trig problem:

[image]

And you get $A_3 = \sqrt{1 + y^2}$ and $p_3 = \arctan(-y)$ so
$$\sqrt{1 + y^2}\sin(x + \arctan(-y)) = z$$
$$x = \arcsin\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{1 + y^2}}\right) + \arctan(y)$$